How do i get all WebSockets in the current page using puppeteer in TypeScript
I am trying to get all WebSockets from the current page and save them to a variable, so I can just do socket.send to send messages through them
I've tried to do this:
const prototype = await page.evaluateHandle("WebSocket.prototype");
    var socketInstances = await page.queryObjects(prototype);
    await page.evaluate((instances:Array<WebSocket>) => {
            instances[0].send("message");
        }, socketInstances);

const cdp = await page.createCDPSession();
    await cdp.send('Network.enable');
    await cdp.send('Page.enable');

cdp.on("Network.webSocketFrameReceived", response => console.log(response));
    cdp.on('Network.webSocketFrameSent', response => console.log(response));


by doing this, i can listen to all messages received by the WebSockets, but i haven't figured out how to send messages through the WebSockets without calling page.evaluate every time. I've tried getting a reference to the WebSockets like this:
await cdp.send('Runtime.enable');
const { exceptionDetails, result: remoteObject } = await cdp.send('Runtime.evaluate', {
        expression: 'WebSocket'
      });
await cdp.send("Runtime.queryObjects", {prototypeObjectId: remoteObject.objectId});


but I can't get this to work. Any ideas on how to do this? Maybe in an even easier way?

I've stumbled upon the same exact problem and can't say I'm happy with the solution I found, but it works nonetheless. I'm using playwright instead of puppeteer, but CDP shouldn't be dependent on the chromium wrapper used.
const dtClient = await page.context().newCDPSession(page);
await dtClient.send('Network.enable');

dtClient.on('Network.webSocketCreated', async ({requestId, url}) => {
    const { result } = await dtClient.send('Runtime.evaluate', {expression: 'WebSocket.prototype'});

    const { objects } = await dtClient.send("Runtime.queryObjects", {prototypeObjectId: result.objectId!});

    await dtClient.send('Runtime.callFunctionOn', {
        objectId: objects.objectId,
        functionDeclaration: `function () {
            const ws = this[0];
            setTimeout(() => {
            ws.send('[1, "Testing"]');
            }, 500)
        }`
    });
});

this in the context of the function provided to Runtime.callFunctionOn refers to the object specified by the objectId. In this case, an Array object containing references to WebSockets. Keep in mind the WebSocket may still be in the CONNECTING state when callFunctionOn executes
